# Permute array elements maximizing the distance vector Java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, permutation, distance

Suppose `v = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` , I need to permute it so that the new indices of
 each element are as distant as possible. I mean, minimizing the variance in the distance vector and, at the same time, maxim. For example, being d the distance vector:

`Opt 1 -> [0, 4, 1, 3, 2], d = [3, 2, 1, 0]` -> NO OK! It isn't uniform. 
`Opt 2 -> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], d = [0, 0, 0, 0]` -> NO OK! It's uniform but not maxim. 
`Opt 3 -> [0, 2, 4, 1, 3], d = [1, 1, 2, 1]` -> Maybe good option, I don't know if it's the best...

There is some `algorithm/procedure/idea` to do that? I've to do it in Java, maybe exist some
 built method to do that, but I don't find it...

Comment: I think the primary issue here is understanding the problem.  Can you rephrase what you mean?  Could you tell us what would be the optimal value for this array (if it is too complicated to solve, try with a simpler array perhaps)?

Comment: In fact 3rd option is the best in this example. I meant that it isn't unique, d = [1,2,1,1] is another one... uniqueness isn't a problem. Sorry about "Maybe good option", actually is the best option.

Comment: What do you mean by uniform? And how exactly is the distance vector computed?

Comment: `[0, 3, 4, 1, 2]` gives `d = [2, 2, 2, 2]` in my understanding, or did I miss something? What's the first element (0) about? Does uniform mean that `max(distance) - min(distance) <= 1`?

Comment: Maybe I see what you mean.  `1, 1, 2, 1` would be the differences between `0, 2, 4, 1, 3`, correct?

Comment: @Ronald Your array would give `3, 1, 3, 1`  (3 - 0, 4 - 3, 4 - 1, 2 - 1).

Comment: I may be mistaken, but this strikes me as an NP problem.  Let me think on this and then I'll write an answer.

Comment: Distance: d[i] = v[i+1] - v[i] for all i \in [0, v.length-2].
Uniform: d[i] must be as similar as posible among themselves. I mean, Each d[i] for all i must be as close as possible to mean(d).

Comment: @Neil: it probably is NP, but it can be done for small sets. I still don't understand this distance vector. How is it calculated? I first thought it is the differences between old and new position, but that seems not to be the case. But your calculation doesn't give me a clue too, since in the example that would lead to `2, 2, 3, 2` not `1, 1, 2, 1`

Comment: @Ronald Amanda, correct me if I'm wrong.  It is the absolute value of the difference.

Comment: @Neil: Distances are always positive or zero, so I didn't explicitly mention `abs()`.

Comment: @Neil [2,2,3,2] is a solution too, the difference is that I've 0 in mind, but it's the same... And yes, it is absolute value of the difference.

Comment: @Ronald `v= [0, 3, 4, 1, 2]` gives `[2, 0, 2, 0]`

Comment: @Amanda: So I understood in the mean time. Although I don't understand why you keep subtracting 1. Does the distance between x and x equal -1 ???

Comment: @AmandaGarci So, please, fix your question: "must be uniform" is not correct. You actually aim to minimize the variance in the distance vector.

Comment: @Ronald My problem satisfies the measure of distance function is `d[i] = v[i+1]-v[i]-1`, you are right. Thank you.

Comment: @Amanda: although you might have a solution now, I have another question: Is the idea to maximize the distance first and then take care of the uniformity, or the other way around? In other words, what's better: `|d| = 10, u = 3` or `|d| = 12, u = 7`? (Thereby: `|d|` is the length of the distance vector, `u` is the variance in the distance vector). Or do you have some formula which makes the pair measurable?

Comment: That is a great point @Ronald, I was thinking about it right now. I don't know how to handle both measures simultaneously, because they belong to different domains, I guess I have to weigh them to find a good solution. Anyway, this is a problem related to the printing codes in a production line. Printers must distribute codes so two consecutive batches haven't similar codes and that must occur in all production line, so I guess it is more important `u` than `|d|`. However it would be interesting to know the joint solution so codes are as far apart as possible.

Comment: So far I've been thinking more theoretically about the problem. I didn't prove it yet, but to me it seems obvious that if the vector is sorted, `|d|` will be minimal. Now if you take the highest value in the vector and put it in the middle of a new vector. Then you take the two smallest values and put those each on one side of the first value. Next you take the two highest values and then again the lowest values. And so on. That should give a quite maximized `|d|`. It might even be the absolute maximum. But the variance will be horrible. Without a rule for a trade off, I'm pretty stuck now.

Comment: In your example that would give `{2,0,4,1,3}`, with `d = {2,4,3,2}` (or `{1,3,2,1}` in your original notation). My next thought is to put the values near the mean next to the highest value. The idea is to distribute the distances towards the less extreme values. That will reduce the variance, without reducing `|d|` too much

Comment: @Ronald: Your first thought may be good. I think if the vector is divided into subintervals, and we applie same logic,it will improve the variance. It's possible distribute the highest values into subintervals and continue with your idea. Then the key is select subrange lengths. For example: Suppose `v=[0,1,2...12]`, then we'll have `[6,12,7,4,11,5,2,10,3,8,0,9,1]` (if I divide it in 4 intervals), so `d =[6,5,3,7,6,3,8,7,5,8,9,8]`...

Comment: @Ronald: Sorry for omitting the data, but I think it is important to say that the vector length can be arbitrarily large, as 30M, I think it is statistically significant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be able to post my little test program, I post an answer now.

```
import java.util.*;

class x {
        static final int testseries[] = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97 };

        public static void main(String argv[])
        {
                Vector orig = new Vector();
                for (int i = 0; i < testseries.length; ++i) orig.add(new Integer(testseries[i]));

                Vector dist = getD(orig);
                System.out.println("d min = " + getAbsD(dist) + "\tUniformity = " + getUniformity(dist));
                printVector(orig);
                printVector(dist);
                System.out.println();

                Vector v = reorder1(orig);
                dist = getD(v);
                System.out.println("d     = " + getAbsD(dist) + "\tUniformity = " + getUniformity(dist));
                printVector(v);
                printVector(dist);
                System.out.println();

                v = reorder2(orig);
                dist = getD(v);
                System.out.println("d     = " + getAbsD(dist) + "\tUniformity = " + getUniformity(dist));
                printVector(v);
                printVector(dist);
                System.out.println();

                return;
        }

        //
        // This method constructs the Distance Vector from the input
        // 
        public static Vector getD(Vector orig)
        {
                Vector v = new Vector();
                for (int i = 0; i < orig.size() - 1; ++i) {
                        int a = ((Integer) orig.get(i)).intValue();
                        int b = ((Integer) orig.get(i + 1)).intValue();
                        v.add(new Integer(Math.abs(a - b)));
                }
                return v;
        }

        public static double getAbsD(Vector orig)
        {
                double d = 0;
                Vector v = getD(orig);

                for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
                        int a = ((Integer) v.get(i)).intValue();
                        d += a * a;
                }
                return Math.sqrt(d);
        }

        public static double getUniformity(Vector dist)
        {
                double u = 0;
                double mean = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < dist.size(); ++i) {
                        mean += ((Integer) dist.get(i)).intValue();
                }
                mean /= dist.size();

                for (int i = 0; i < dist.size(); ++i) {
                        int a = ((Integer) dist.get(i)).intValue();
                        u += (a - mean) * (a - mean);
                }

                return u / dist.size();
        }

        //
        // This method reorders the input vector to maximize the distance
        // It is assumed that the input is sorted (direction doesn't matter)
        //
        // Note: this is only the basic idea of the distribution algorithm
        //       in this form it only works if (n - 1) mod 4 == 0
        //
        public static Vector reorder1(Vector orig)
        {
                Integer varr[] = new Integer[orig.size()];

                int t, b, lp, rp;
                t = orig.size() - 1;
                b = 0;
                lp = t / 2 - 1;
                rp = t / 2 + 1;
                varr[t/2] = (Integer) orig.get(t); t--;
                while (b < t) {
                        varr[lp] = (Integer) orig.get(b); b++;
                        varr[rp] = (Integer) orig.get(b); b++;
                        lp--; rp++;
                        varr[lp] = (Integer) orig.get(t); t--;
                        varr[rp] = (Integer) orig.get(t); t--;
                        lp--; rp++;
                }

                Vector result = new Vector();
                for (int i = 0; i < orig.size(); ++i) result.add(varr[i]);

                return result;
        }

        //
        // This method reorders the input vector to maximize the distance
        // It is assumed that the input is sorted (direction doesn't matter)
        //
        // Note: this is only the basic idea of the distribution algorithm
        //       in this form it only works if (n - 1) mod 4 == 0
        //
        public static Vector reorder2(Vector orig)
        {
                Integer varr[] = new Integer[orig.size()];

                int t, b, lp, rp;
                t = orig.size() - 1;
                b = orig.size() / 2 - 1;
                lp = t / 2 - 1;
                rp = t / 2 + 1;
                varr[t/2] = (Integer) orig.get(t); t--;
                while (b > 0) {
                        varr[lp] = (Integer) orig.get(b); b--;
                        varr[rp] = (Integer) orig.get(b); b--;
                        lp--; rp++;
                        varr[lp] = (Integer) orig.get(t); t--;
                        varr[rp] = (Integer) orig.get(t); t--;
                        lp--; rp++;
                }

                Vector result = new Vector();
                for (int i = 0; i < orig.size(); ++i) result.add(varr[i]);

                return result;
        }

        //
        // to make everything better visible
        //
        public static void printVector(Vector v)
        {
                String sep = "";
                System.out.print("{");
                for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
                        System.out.print(sep + v.get(i));
                        sep = ", ";
                }
                System.out.println("}");
        }
}
```

Since the complexity of the Algorithm is `O(n)` (n is the vector size) this will work for (very) large sets too. (If the input has to be sorted first, complexity is `n log(n)`).

As this little program proves, my original idea (reorder1) won't give the best result with respect to the distance. So `reorder2()` would be the algorithm of my choice. (It's simple, fast and delivers acceptable results, as it seems).

The test values used are some of my favourite numbers. There exist a few more ;-)

Comment: Thank you @Ronald, `reorder2` is a great and simple solution. (...and yes, there exist infinitely more :))

Comment: `reorder1` and `reorder2` have some problem in which the last element is not inserted, and a `NullPointerException` is thrown in `getD` when it tries to handle it.

Comment: That's why I wrote in the comment that it's just the idea of the algorithm, only working for specific `n` (`(n - 1) mod 4 == 0`). So it's more like a proof of concept than production proof. But it should be comparatively easy to implement a similar algorithm for other `n`. (`n` even, `(n - 1) mod 4 == 2`). Anyway, the program as printed works in my environment.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem correctly, you want to create the maximum and most uniform distance array possible.

### Brute force

Unfortunately I believe this problem is NP-hard, meaning if it absolutely has to be the optimal solution, you may be better off cycling through all possible permutations of the array and picking the best.  If you have a relatively small array, this may, in effect, be your best bet.

The pseudocode for finding the best solution using brute force would be something like:

```
var max = MIN;
for each permutation of array 
   var score = getScore(permutation)
   if(score > max) 
      max = score;
end
```

`getScore` represents how you determine what makes up a "best array".  I saw that in your best solution for what you provided, there was a "2" among the other distance values of 1, which means you tolerate solutions with non-uniform answers.  My suggestion would be something along the lines of adding up all distances and subtracting a penalty for each distance which varies from the most common.  How much you subtract will determine how important it is that they are all uniform (perform some trial and error to understand what works best).

### Genetic algorithms

If you want a really good solution, but not necessarily the best, then you should consider using [genetic algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm).

If you're new to Java, I apologize!  This is definitely not the best thing to start off with if you're new to Java.

The idea behind genetic algorithms is that you create a population of list orderings (could be a list of indexes).  It doesn't have to hold every possible combination, just around 50 or so.  With each turn of the algorithm, you evaluate each solution's "score" (equivalent of `getScore` mentioned above).  Then, 50/2 times, you randomly select two solutions with weighted probability favoring those solutions which had a higher score and you create two new solutions from the two parent solutions.  You then have a new population which you can then perform another turn, and so forth and so on.

If you continue in this way, often the trend emerges that you will see scores improve in the population and if done properly, these solutions will improve as well.  Consider always directly including the solution with the best score in each turn, or you risk to lose your very best solution at each turn.

### Simulated annealing

[Simulated annealing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing) is the process of modifying a solution slightly in order to improve or worsen a solution.  If it worsens, then you keep the solution you had before.  If it improves, you keep the new solution.  In either case, you continue to modify the solution until no change to the solution brings a better one.  This is a very simple algorithm, but it is guaranteed to find you at least a local maximum.

In your case, the changes you would be making would be the list ordering.  Say rather than use list ordering 0,1,2,3, you try 0,2,1,3 and you find its score is better.  You keep 0,2,1,3, and you try to modify something else.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you @Neil, I had to program some genetic algorithms fitness based  at university and it isn't solution to my problem, I mean, it's solution, but I only want mess a list, not worth it! :D

Brute force is not option at all, mess the list is a small part of a big process that must be fast... Maybe it isn't possible mess it the best way.

Comment: @AmandaGarci I expanded my answer to include simulated annealing.  Please take a look.  This may not offer the best solution, but this is a quick way to go about it.

Comment: I believe you mean NP-complete or NP-hard. NP just means verifiable in polynomial time.

Comment: @Dukeling You're right, I did mean NP-hard.  I don't think it is possible to verify that a solution is optimal in polynomial time.  Made the proper adjustments.

Comment: Thank you @Neil, simulated annealing is likely the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the problem is quite easy if the dimension n of your vector is odd. Then d = (n -1)/2 is prime with n and you just have to build a star polygon (d, n)(see stars polygons or stellation on wikipedia). Same thing is to add the distance d (modulo n). If the dimension is even  and if d = n/2 - 1 is prime with n, same method. More complications if not. But I confess that it is the solution of the circular problem (where the distance among the last element and the first one is also taken in account).
Example : for 1 à 9, distance 4, we obtain : 1,5,9,4*,8,3*,7,2*,5  (* 4 = 13 (modulo 9), id for the others *).
The distance is constant and max (in the circular point of view),

Brg